# How to recognize a large amount of words using CMUSphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I've been trying to have Sphinx detect all words in its dictionary (around 130k) using a .gram file, but it processes for about 30 seconds, then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.HashMap.newNode(HashMap.java:1734)
at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:630)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.addLeftContext(FlatLinguist.java:754)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.pushLeftContexts(FlatLinguist.java:738)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.pushLeftContexts(FlatLinguist.java:742)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.pushLeftContexts(FlatLinguist.java:742)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.pushLeftContexts(FlatLinguist.java:718)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist$GState.collectContexts(FlatLinguist.java:846)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.compileGrammar(FlatLinguist.java:415)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.allocate(FlatLinguist.java:326)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:602)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.allocate(Decoder.java:109)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:182)
at voce.SpeechRecognizer.<init>(SpeechRecognizer.java:94)
at voce.SpeechInterface.init(SpeechInterface.java:79)
at recognitionTest.main(recognitionTest.java:9)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Is there a different, or a more memory efficient way to achieve this task?

I am using a library that utilizes Sphinx called [Voce](http://voce.sourceforge.net/) to make it a bit simpler to do recognition and synthesizing, if that matters.

Comment: "detect all words in its dictionary" - what does it mean?

Comment: @Alexander Solovets Sphinx has a dictionary file that lists all supported words and their pronunciations. I formated those words into a .gram file and tried to use it with my program.

Answer (score 1):

CMUSphinx can not recognize such a long list from the grammar, it particular it is complex with Voce which does not wrap CMUSphinx properly. We do not recommend using Voce.

You can use statistical n-gram language model to create a large vocabulary recognizer. You can learn more about it from [documentation](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) or [Transcriber](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java) demo.

Comment: I downloaded the Jar files from here [https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~sphinx4](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~sphinx4), which is the place that the tutorial recommended for them to be downloaded. The problem is, whenever I try to run one of the demo classes I get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: http://pastebin.com/cseeHA6Q . I think it might be because the Jars are outdated. Do you happen to know why this is happening?

Comment: You need to provide more information on what jar did you download exactly and what other jars are in your classpath.

Comment: My bad. I downloaded the sphinx4-data.jar and the sphinx4-core.jar. I made a new project so those were the only jars in my classpath.

Comment: Please provide exact filenames you downloaded

Comment: [sphinx4-data-1.0-20150630.174256-9.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-data/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-data-1.0-20150630.174256-9.jar) and [sphinx4-core-1.0-20150630.174404-9.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-core-1.0-20150630.174404-9.jar). Clicking on the links will download the files.